# Ref undefined in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, ref

When I try to use slider `ref` inside `functionB` I'm getting ref undefined error.What am i doing wrong here?

```js
class somecomp extends Component {
  
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.slider = React.createRef;   
 }

 componentDidMount(){        
   this.functionA();
 }

 functionA = () => {
   functionB();
 }

 functionB = () => {   
   // When i call slider ref here im getting ref undefined  
 }
   
 render() {     
   return (
     <div ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}></div>                                                          
   );
 }
}

export default somecomp;
```

Comment: First and foremost, `createRef` is a function.  You have to call it with `createRef()`.  Start there, because otherwise your question seems like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the root of your problem here

```
this.slider = React.createRef
```

You are not create ref you pass function which creates ref to slider

Try to use it in such way

```
this.slider = React.createRef();
```

Also this

```
<div ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}></div>
```

Might be simplified to this

```
<div ref={this.slider}></div>
```

Also do not forget to user `current` property of ref
In your situation it will be

```
const node = this.slider.current;
```

Comment: Which problem do you have?

Comment: i still get ref undefined

Comment: I assume you might forget to use current. const node = this.slider.current; prop when you try to access reference. Please check answer update.

Comment: i updated the original code,Please check function B is the interval function here

Answer (score 0):

Few problems you've in your code that should be corrected https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-lamport-gfv9j

```
class somecomp extends Component {
  
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.slider = React.createRef; // use React.createRef() at here  
 }

 componentDidMount(){        
   this.functionA();
 }

 functionA = () => {
   functionB(); // use this.functionB() at here
 }

 functionB = () => {  
    console.log("this.slider", this.slider); 
   // When i call slider ref here im getting ref undefined  
 }
   
 render() {     
   return (
     <div ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)}></div>                                                          
   );
 }
}

export default somecomp;
```